# Find a point old position after zoom using java script

Tags: javascript, zooming

I am working on this "simple" problem for hours with no success, although I tried many ways to solve it using all kind of solutions suggested in SO.

My problem is as follows:

I have a point on a canvas, which when I click on it my app does something, after identifying the point by comparing the mouse click coordinates to the stored position of the point.

After zooming into the point, using the mouse wheel, I click on the point again but the mouse coordinates no longer fits the stored position of the point.

I need to either transform the mouse coordinates to it's coordinates before the zoom, so I will be able to compare to the stored position, or to transform the stored position to the new canvas so it can be compare to the coordinates of the mouse. Any of the solution is fine by me.

I know the following data:

The "scale" value,

The size of the canvas (top, left, width, height),

The new origin of the canvas (top, left)

I would like a solution using java script.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out and it is quite simple, once I understood the concept.

1. Save the new canvas origin after doing the zoom (in JS it is calling ctx.translate() and ctx.scale(), where ctx is the canvas context.
2. When need to calculate the mouse position in the old coordinate system, one has to add back the moved origin of the canvas, and multiply by the scale factor.

   seat.x = (-new_org.x + pos.x) / scale;
   seat.y = (-new_org.y + pos.y) / scale;

where pos is the calculated mouse pointer

```
pos.x = event.clientX - .getBoundingClientRect().left;
pos.y = event.clientY - .getBoundingClientRect().top;
```